# Printing prn files to Network Printer (Zebra)

Tags: python, zebra-printers

I have a general question regarding the use of Zebra modules in python.
Currently I am able to send prn files to local Zebra printers with parameters without any issue. The issue is when I am trying to use a network printer I receive a printer name invalid error.
The module that is giving me issues is the "zebra" module. When I try to use the module "simple_zpl2", nothing happens. No data is being sent to the printer. When I use the example command from Zebra's webpage, I can print their example but I cannont print my own prn file.

Zebras Example Code works:

```
import socket              
mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)         
host = "10.80.209.106" 
port = 9100   
try:           
    mysocket.connect((host, port)) #connecting to host
    mysocket.send(b"^XA^A0N,50,50^FO50,50^FDSocket Test^FS^XZ")#using bytes
    mysocket.close () #closing connection
except:
    print("Error with the connection")
```

My Verion

```
def print_label(printer_name)
import socket              
mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)         
host = printers[printer_name]   <-- This is a dict and returns the ip address 
port = 9100   < -- left as is 
try:           
    mysocket.connect((host, port)) #connecting to host
    mysocket.send(ZEBRA_TEMPLATE_VAR.format(var1,var2,var3,var4,etc
))

    mysocket.close () #closing connection
except:
    print("Error with the connection")
```

Comment: can you post the content of your own prn file?

Answer (score 0):

Your ZPL could be wrong. Or you have to encode your string differently.